# Set Default Country

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-10

I want to set default country "Hong Kong" for country_id field. So what function i write for that in odoo10. Now my python code is below:

py code:

```
@api.depends('country_id')
def _get_default_country(self, context=None):
    if self.country_id:
        return {'domain': [('country_id', '=', self.country_id.id)]}
    print "yes:", 235
    return True

_defaults = {
    'country_id': _get_default_country
}
country_info = fields.Char(compute='_get_default_country', 
                           string='Default Country')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return value always match with field data-type. In your case, you are storing "char" value and return "Boolean" (true/false). That's doesn't make sense.

If you want to drop-down list then change "country_info" data-type from "Char" to "Many2one" and your default function should return "integer" value as per your logic.

Comment: Yes, you are right Odedra. I have done this by adding this following code:                                                                                         country_id = fields.Many2one('res.country', "Country", change_default=True, default=_get_default_country)            @api.model
    def _get_default_country(self):
        print "yes:", 95
        return 95

Answer (score 2):

Python Lambda functions are mainly used in combination with the functions filter(), map() and reduce().

**ODOO 10**

Python code:

```
country_id = fields.Many2one('res.country', string='Country', default=lambda self: self.env['res.country'].browse([(95)]))
```

XML code:

```
<field name="country_id" readonly="1"/>
```